# FFmpeg SDI to XDCam MXF (Audio Outsync Issue)

Tags: audio, synchronization, sdi

We have a requirement to capture SDI input 8 channels using Decklink card and the output would be in XDCam 50 MXF,8channels . Below is the command that we are using.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -channels 8 -pixel_format uyvy422 -rtbufsize 702000k -framerate 25 -i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture" -map 0 -r 25 -s 1920X1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -vcodec mpeg2video -non_linear_quant 1 -flags +ildct+ilme -top 1 -dc 10 -intra_vlc 1 -qmax 6 -lmin "1*QP2LAMBDA"  -rc_max_vbv_use 1 -rc_min_vbv_use 1 -b:v 50000k -minrate 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 36408333 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -bf 2 -f mxf d:/final.mxf
```

The resultant output is not proper. The Audio and Video is out of sync. Please suggest if we are doing anything wrong.